# Php mail() returns true but doesn't receive email

Tags: php, html, email, web

I am developing a website with html, css, js. I have a tab with contact. I would like to send an email from the contact form to my email address with the details. Searching on the internet I can see that there is a php function, so I used it. I can see that the `mail()` function returns 1 but I don't receive the email. Any ideas? How can I solve this problem?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && 
    isset($_POST['email']) &&
    isset($_POST['subject']) &&
    isset($_POST['mensaje']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $to = 'prueba@gmail.com';
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    $body = '<html>
                <body>
                <h2>Ha rellenado el formulario de contacto en la web</h2>
                <hr>
                <p>Nombre:<br>'.$name.'</p>
                <p>Email:<br>'.$email.'</p>
                <p>Asunto:<br>'.$subject.'</p>
                <p>Mensaje:<br>'.$mensaje.'</p>
            </body>
        </html>';

    //headers
    $headers  = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
    //send
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($send){
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'ha funcionado';
    }else{
        echo 'no ha funcionado';
    }      
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there could be almost a million reasons, most of them outside your control

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder?

Comment: Yes! it´s empty.

Comment: if you are on live server check error log file